# EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined / EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using MVC, ASP Identity and EntityFramework.

I am trying to make my customized ASP Identity models and have it interact with some custom tables, I want to expand the original.

I keep getting the same error over and over and over, have been trying to fix this for 2 full days now.

The error is as follows:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Kportal.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Kportal.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

I have tried all of the solutions I could find in other questions to no avail, this is slowly turning into a nightmare.

Here is my code;
The Entities : IdentityDbContext

```
public class Entities : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUsers, Role,
    int, UserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, UserClaim>
    {
        public Entities()
            : base("name=Entities")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Entities>(null);
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        public static Entities Create()
        {
            return new Entities();
        }

        //public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUsers> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Finding> Findings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        //public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUserProject> ApplicationUserProjects { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> ApplicationUserRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().Ignore(c => c.PhoneNumber)
                                          .Ignore(c => c.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                                          .Ignore(c => c.TwoFactorEnabled)
                                          .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEndDateUtc)
                                          .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEnabled)
                                          .Ignore(c => c.AccessFailedCount)
                                          .Ignore(c => c.UserName);

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("ApplicationUser", "dbo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim", "dbo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasKey<int>(l => l.Id).ToTable("Role", "dbo");

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId })
                                                  .ToTable("UserLogin", "dbo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().HasKey(l => new { l.ApplicationUserId, l.RoleId })
                                                 .ToTable("ApplicationUserRole", "dbo");

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUsers>().Property(r => r.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().Property(r => r.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().Property(r => r.UserId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().Property(r => r.Id);
        }
    }
```

The ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
    {
        public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public override int RoleId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateChanged { get; set; }
        public int CreateUser { get; set; }
        public int ChangeUser { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUsers ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

The UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin

```
public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
{
    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUsers ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

I hope this is enough information, any clue as to why these errors keep coming?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the primary key of your new custom table, Example:

```
[Key]
public int UserLoginId { get; set; }
```

If you need a composite key with your current columns then use:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public string LoginProvider { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public string ProviderKey { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order = 2)]
public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
```